# setting up local dev enviroment with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm setting up my local test pc (WIN10 with xampp) to dev my web projects.
What I achieved:

- visiting https://example.com will show the remote production version
- visiting http://local.example.com will show the local development version (http so i dont have to deal with certificate issues)

The piece I'm missing is the /public/.htaccess, that I still have to comment each time I'm testing something. The condition and rule are:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

How do I rewrite this condition to ignore the rule if the request is made from local.example.com

Thanks

Comment: added the condition   RewriteCond !(.*) http:/local.example.com seems to seal the deal. any drawbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: thank you for answering. Would it be safer this approach than what I wrote?

Comment: It is always better to compare host name instead of whole url.This is standard Rewrite condition to check host name.